# How to associate a user to multiple scheme of a database?

Tags: oracle

I have a Database with several schema and i want to create an user who can log In different scheme of my database.

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [proxy feature](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4003.htm#i2058312) to enable a user to connect as another user/schema:

> The proxy_clause lets you control the ability of an enterprise user [..] to connect as the database user being altered.

Given schemas `A` and `B` and user `USR`, you could:

```
ALTER USER A GRANT CONNECT THROUGH USR;
ALTER USER B GRANT CONNECT THROUGH USR;
```

This would allow USR to connect as A or B using his identifiers, as shown in [this askTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:83012348058#408884400346292168):

```
CONNECT USR[A]/PASSUSR
```

This will make `USR` able to connect as if he was `A`.